# Character coding conversion error when using Emacs with Outlook

Tags: emacs, character-encoding, outlook

I'm currently using [outlookedit.el](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9198) to roundtrip e-mails from Outlook in order to remain sane when corresponding with people. It is working beautifully except for when I have to use special characters, in this case "åäö" which are used in swedish.

When I open an e-mail containing these characters in Outlook (*C-c o e*) they all look ok in Emacs but when I save my changes back to Outlook (*C-c o s*) "*åäö*" turns into "*Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶*" switching back to Emacs (*C-c o e*) they are converted properly by Emacs into "*åäö*" again.

If, instead of using *outlookedit.el* I copy/paste text between Outlook and Emacs character conversion appears to be performed perfectly but I would prefer not to have to do it this way.

I've tried to force Outlook to encode e-mails both into US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 under *Options* -> *Mail Format* -> *International Options...* but the result is always the same.

How can I (preferably) modify my .emacs to handle the character conversion properly or reconfigure Outlook to make roundtripping these characters work?

My current Emacs configuration is up for inspection at http://github.com/dholm/dotemacs/.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same for your Emacs buffer? (i.e., set the coding-system explicitly to match that of Outlook) http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Text-Coding.html

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that between the Shell, and outlookedit.el, something is happening with your character encoding.  You could try setting the default coding system of your buffer to either UTF-8, ASCII, or CP-1252 (The windows default).